# How can I print script block content in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, function, error-handling, retry-logic, scriptblock

**Hi guys, I want to create a function that will be checking execution of selected commands and in case of catched failure retry 3 times and display the command name with the retry message. I placed a test command "Test Connection" between the function brackets to be evaluted, retry seems to be working, however I can not get the command name to be printed. I tried with "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock)", but it prints out the whole function intead of that executed line that I'm checking. Can anyone please advice here?
Thanks a lot in advance**

```
function Execute-WithRetry([ScriptBlock]$command) {

    $Stoploop = $false
    $count = 0
 
    do {
        try {
            & $command
            Write-Host "Download completed"
            $Stoploop = $true
        }
        catch {
            if ($count -eq 3) {
               
                Write-Host "Could not download after 3 retries."
                $Stoploop = $true
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "Could not download the files retrying in 5 seconds..."
                Write-Host "Executing: $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock)"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }
        }
        $count++
    }
    While  ($Stoploop -eq $false)
    pause

    }


Execute-WithRetry {
  Test-Connection -ComputerName 192.10.129.15 -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `$MyInvocation.Line`

Comment: it will only show a line number not a whole command, in my case "Test-Connection -...."

Comment: You are mistaken, the `Line` property contains a string - the line on which the statement that threw the error starts. Try grabbing the invocation info directly from the error record if `$MyInvocation` isn't giving you anything: `try {Test-Connection nonexistingfqdn -ErrorAction Stop}catch {Write-Host "Failed at '$($_.InvocationInfo.Line |% Trim)'"}`

Comment: Sure I will try.

Comment: It shows me the following: Failed at '& $command'

Comment: And $MyInvocation.Line on its own prints out me the name of the function "Execute-WithRetry" instead of the "Test-Connection" that is placed in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want just the "offending" *line* from the script block, grab the invocation info from the *error record* inside the `catch` block (as opposed to `$MyInvocation`) and use the `Line` property to get the line on which the statement that failed starts:

```
function Invoke-Retry {
  param([scriptblock]$Command)

  $stop = $false
  $count = 0

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  do {
    try {
      &$Command

      Write-Host "Download completed"
      $stop = $true
    }
    catch {
      if ($count -ge 3) {
        Write-Host "Could not download after 3 retries."
        $stop = $true
      }
      else {
        Write-Host "Could not download the files, retrying in 5 seconds"
        Write-Host "Error occurred while executing: `n>> $($_.InvocationInfo.Line)" -ForegroundColor Red
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
      }
    }
    $count++
  } while (-not $stop)
  pause
}
```

Which should give you the actual line from the script block:

```
PS ~> Invoke-Retry {
  Test-Connection -ComputerName doesntexist
}
Could not download the files retrying in 5 seconds
Error occurred while executing:
>>   Test-Connection -ComputerName doesntexist

Could not download the files retrying in 5 seconds
Error occurred while executing:
>>   Test-Connection -ComputerName doesntexist

Could not download the files retrying in 5 seconds
Error occurred while executing:
>>   Test-Connection -ComputerName doesntexist

Could not download after 3 retries.
Press Enter to continue...:
```

***Note**: starting with version 7.4, the invocation info class also exposes the full extent of any multiline statements via the [`Statement` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.statement?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#system-management-automation-invocationinfo-statement)*

Comment: Nicely done (my answer took the question literally). Good to know about `.InvocationInfo.Statement`; as of PowerShell 7.4.0-rc.1, there's a (small) problem with it: see [GitHub issue #20638](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20638).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the heads up, looks like we need more tests ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Preface:

- This answer addresses the question as asked: how to obtain the *entire* source-code representation of the script block whose invocation triggered an error.
- [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77418506/45375) demonstrates how to extract the *specific line* inside the script block's source code that triggered the error.

---

It looks like you're looking for the *source-code representation* of the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) stored in `$command`.

Calling `.ToString()` on a script block returns just that (without the enclosing `{` and `}`) and, therefore, simply referencing a script block inside `"..."`, an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) has the same effect.

Therefore, this should do what you want (the surrounding `{` and `}` are solely to give the full appearance of the original script-block literal):

```bash
Write-Host "Executing: {$command}"
```

Note:

- The string representation is exactly what you place inside  `{...}`, i.e. a script-block *literal*, and can therefore include newlines.

---

A simplified example:

```bash
# Sample function that prints the source code of a given script block.
function Foo { param([scriptblock] $Command) "Source code: {$Command}" }

# Sample call
# ->
#  "Source code: { Get-Date -Format 'yyyy' }" 
Foo -Command { Get-Date -Format 'yyyy' }
```

Calling `.ToString()` directly on a script-block literal makes the behavior obvious:

```bash
# -> " Get-Date -Format 'yyyy' "
{ Get-Date -Format 'yyyy' }.ToString()
```